# unable to find a version of silverlight developer runtime installed

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2012, silverlight-5.0, visual-studio-lightswitch

In the following environment:

-VS2012

-Windows 7 64bit

-Microsoft Silverlight 5 SDK

I have created a few lightswitch applications in VS2012 but I am running into an error when attempting to create a new one or open an existing lightswitch project. I receive a pop-up that says "unable to find a version of silverlight developer runtime installed".

There is a link on the pop-up which starts a download but after downloading it, I still receive the same error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by doing the following :

- I went into "Uninstall a program" and noticed that I had 4 different Silverlight related items installed.

  - Microsoft Silverlight
  - Microsoft Silverlight SDK3
  - Microsoft Silverlight SDK4
  - Microsoft Silverlight SDK5

I just uninstalled the first item, "Microsoft Silverlight" then reinstalled the appropriate (32 or 64 bit) Microsoft Silverlight SDK5 from the following link:  http://www.silverlight.net/downloads .

Don't use the link that is given in VS 2012.  Doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I have a slight different solution for Visual Studio 2010. After uninstall the current Silverlight Runtime, I got it to work if I download it from Visual Studio suggested url.

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2010 as well, and SDeezy's solution for VS2012 did not work for me, but this did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found to find the most current Silverlight 5 Developer Runtime or End-User Runtime, is to search the downloads for the latest Silverlight bits.  All other suggestions seem to take you on a wild goose chase depending on what version of Visual Studio or OS you are using.

[Search Microsoft Downloads](http://search.microsoft.com/en-us/DownloadResults.aspx?q=silverlight&sortby=-availabledate)

Just look for the latest "Security Update for Microsoft Silverlight" entry.

Answer (score 0):

The Silverlight Security Update KB2890788 is what fixed it for me, after trying uninstall and re-install without success.